# How to use iPhone MFMailComposer using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova, mfmailcomposer

How to use iPhone MFMailComposer using phonegap?

I am using phonegap framework to develop my application. But i dont want to use "mailto", as while tapping on that it launches iphone default mail application.

My requirement is to send mail same like MFMailComposer does in default iOS sdk.

Let me know if there are any ways available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer below two link for your reference. this will help you to open MailComposer view in Phone gap.
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer